# How to uninstall Apache with command line

Tags: windows, apache, nsis, uninstallation

So I'm trying to find a command to uninstall apache from windows that I have installed earlier with an NSIS script.

Basically apache is part of a package of aplications we use for our program, and when uninstalling our program we uninstall them all. Already working for postgres, java and ruby, but I'm not finding any command for apache.

I tried the wmic command, but it required user to confirm the action. There isn't any httpd uninstall command?

```
httpd -k uninstall
```

simply removes the service.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
sc delete Apache2.4
```

Remove service in windows

Answer (score 7):

On Windows 8.1 I had to run cmd.exe as administrator (even though I was logged in as admin). Otherwise I got an error when trying to execute: httpd.exe -k uninstall

Error:
C:\Program Files\Apache\bin>(OS 5)Access is denied.  : AH00373: Apache2.4: OpenS
ervice failed

Comment: Is this a comment or an answer?

Comment: Looks like an answer to me (and it got several upvotes meanwhile).

Answer (score 1):

I've had this sort of problem.....

The solve: `cmd` / `powershell` run as **ADMINISTRATOR!** I always forget.

Notice: In `powershell`, you need to put `.\` for example:

```
.\httpd -k shutdown .\httpd -k stop .\httpd -k uninstall
```

Result: Removing the `apache2.4` service The `Apache2.4` service has been removed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

`sc delete Apache2.4`

or try this :

`C:\Apache24\bin>httpd -k uninstall`

hope this will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If Apache was installed using NSIS installer it should have left an uninstaller. You should search inside Apache installation directory for executable named `unistaller.exe` or something like that. NSIS uninstallers support `/S` flag by default for silent uninstall. So you can run something like `"C:\Program Files\<Apache installation dir here>\uninstaller.exe" /S`

From NSIS [documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter3.html):

> 3.2.1 Common Options
>
> /NCRC disables the CRC check, unless CRCCheck force was used in the
> script. /S runs the installer or uninstaller silently. See section
> 4.12 for more information. /D sets the default installation directory ($INSTDIR), overriding InstallDir and InstallDirRegKey. It must be the
> last parameter used in the command line and must not contain any
> quotes, even if the path contains spaces. Only absolute paths are
> supported.

Comment: Apache is installed with my installer and it leaves no uninstaller file. It is installer via MSI.

Comment: I couldn't unintall Apache using this recommandation. May be this is possible only when you use the msi installer